# Distributed computing framework in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, networking, distributed

I am looking for a way to make distributed computing over a network (lan). Is there any good framework or a library for this purpose in C/C++.

Comment: A bit more information about what you are trying to do would help.  Are you trying to distribute a single, tightly coupled computation?  Implement a client-server arrangement.  Farm out independent tasks?  Are all of the machines you want to use under your control, or are they desktops that need to be shared with there owners?  There are different approaches that are geared specifically to each one of these, and more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Have you looked at MPI via e.g. [Open MPI](http://www.open-mpi.org) ?